# Why doesn't plt.imshow() display the image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

I have this code, copied from a tutorial:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print X_train.shape
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(X_train[0])
```

No image was displayed. **Why not?**

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the backend of `matplotlib` on my computer. I tested that like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0, 0.25], [0.5, 0.75]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap=plt.get_cmap('hot'), interpolation='nearest',
               vmin=0, vmax=1)
fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

and was able to produce an image:
[image]

I also tried printing `X_train[0]` and it looks right.

Comment: Try adding `plt.show()` at the end of your code snippet.

Comment: This problem often comes up when you copy code from Jupyter

Answer (score 250, accepted):

The solution was as simple as adding `plt.show()` at the end of the code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print X_train.shape
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(X_train[0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This just avoid answering WHY while getting 168 upvote...Strange

Comment: March 2021. The same thing is still missing in the tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

Comment: @Kuo The original code doesn't draw the image because it doesn't contain the line of code that was added. Simple. The title, of course, implies an expectation that `.imshow` itself would do this; but the only way to answer "why doesn't calling `.imshow` draw the image?" **literally** is "because it's not defined to do anything like that".  The natural follow-on question is "well why do they call it `imshow` if it doesn't show an image?", but that's off topic for Stack Overflow; we aren't going to speculate on the thought process of the matplotlib authors.

Answer (score 54):

`plt.imshow` just finishes drawing a picture instead of printing it. If you want to print the picture, you just need to add `plt.show`.

Comment: From that point of view, it would be better and less confusing to rename the "imshow" to "imdraw". Don't you agree?

Comment: @AramParonikyan matplotlib is layers upon layers of confusion and hellish design. One day people will move onto a better library (cv2 is even more confusing)

Answer (score 13):

`plt.imshow` displays the image on the axes, but if you need to display multiple images you use `show()` to finish the figure. The next example shows two figures:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(X_train[0])
plt.show()
plt.imshow(X_train[1])
plt.show()
```

In Google Colab, if you comment out the `show()` method from previous example just a single image will display (the later one connected with `X_train[1]`).

Here is the content from the help:

```
plt.show(*args, **kw)
        Display a figure.
        When running in ipython with its pylab mode, display all
        figures and return to the ipython prompt.

        In non-interactive mode, display all figures and block until
        the figures have been closed; in interactive mode it has no
        effect unless figures were created prior to a change from
        non-interactive to interactive mode (not recommended).  In
        that case it displays the figures but does not block.

        A single experimental keyword argument, *block*, may be
        set to True or False to override the blocking behavior
        described above.



plt.imshow(X, cmap=None, norm=None, aspect=None, interpolation=None, alpha=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, origin=None, extent=None, shape=None, filternorm=1, filterrad=4.0, imlim=None, resample=None, url=None, hold=None, data=None, **kwargs)
        Display an image on the axes.

Parameters
----------
X : array_like, shape (n, m) or (n, m, 3) or (n, m, 4)
    Display the image in `X` to current axes.  `X` may be an
    array or a PIL image. If `X` is an array, it
    can have the following shapes and types:

    - MxN -- values to be mapped (float or int)
    - MxNx3 -- RGB (float or uint8)
    - MxNx4 -- RGBA (float or uint8)

    The value for each component of MxNx3 and MxNx4 float arrays
    should be in the range 0.0 to 1.0. MxN arrays are mapped
    to colors based on the `norm` (mapping scalar to scalar)
    and the `cmap` (mapping the normed scalar to a color).
```